# Difference in runtime C++ using different data types

Tags: c++, long-integer, type-conversion

Ok, so I was doing a tiny project for school and I can't find the answer anywhere to why this small change in code makes it finish in no time when number **m** gets higher. Look at the variable "**k**" I change it from int to long.

I'm trying to find the longest sequence in the Collatz sequence between 1 and 1000000

```
void lengstaRuna() {

    cout << "Hæsta tala?:";
    int m;
    cin >> m;

    int lengstaRuna = 0;
    int talaLengstuRunu = 0;
    int k;

    for(int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
        int lengd = 1;
        k = i;

        while(k != 1) {
            if(k % 2 == 0) {
                k = k/2;
            } else {
                k = k*3 +1;
            }
            lengd++;
        }

        if(lengd > lengstaRuna) {
            lengstaRuna = lengd;
            talaLengstuRunu = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Lengsta runa: " << lengstaRuna << endl;
    cout << "Tala lengstu runu: " << talaLengstuRunu << endl;

}



void lengstaRuna() {

    cout << "Hæsta tala?:";
    int m;
    cin >> m;

    int lengstaRuna = 0;
    int talaLengstuRunu = 0;
    long k;

    for(int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
        int lengd = 1;
        k = i;

        while(k != 1) {
            if(k % 2 == 0) {
                k = k/2;
            } else {
                k = k*3 +1;
            }
            lengd++;
        }

        if(lengd > lengstaRuna) {
            lengstaRuna = lengd;
            talaLengstuRunu = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Lengsta runa: " << lengstaRuna << endl;
    cout << "Tala lengstu runu: " << talaLengstuRunu << endl;

}
```

The question is simple: Why does it run so much faster when input **m**==1000000?

Comment: Faster than what? Change `m` from what?

Comment: What is the goal of this program? @Frosti

Comment: You might want to add some more platform details. The C++ standard only states that ``sizeof(int) <= ``sizeof(long)`` etc. So without knowing what you are dealing with, you cannot expect deep insights.

Comment: On some systems, like Windows, `long` is the same size as `int`. So `k` might still overflow and produce undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what's happening here. Basically, above certain value for your input, the int is overflowing since you are doing k*3.

I modified your code to check this (see below). Upto input value of around 113000, the max your 'k' has to hold is 1570824735 (close to INT_MAX 2147483647). Anything 114000 or above, 'k' overflows and the code goes into uncharted territory. That problem doesn't happen when you use long of course.

```
./a.out 113000
j: 1570824735
Lengsta runa: 354
Tala lengstu runu: 106239

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void lengstaRuna(int m) {


    int lengstaRuna = 0;
    int talaLengstuRunu = 0;
    int k;
    long j = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
        int lengd = 1;
        k = i;

        while(k != 1) {
            if(k % 2 == 0) {
                k = k/2;
            } else {
                if (k*3 > j)
                    j = k*3;
                k = k*3 +1;
            }
            lengd++;
        }

        if(lengd > lengstaRuna) {
            lengstaRuna = lengd;
            talaLengstuRunu = i;
        }
    }
            cout << "j: " << j << endl;

    cout << "Lengsta runa: " << lengstaRuna << endl;
    cout << "Tala lengstu runu: " << talaLengstuRunu << endl;

}
int main (int ac, char** av) {
    std::string::size_type sz; 
lengstaRuna(std::stoi(av[1]));
}
```